# How do I install .run files?

Tags: software-installation

My PC has both Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed. I have installed all my drivers in Windows like Nvidia graphics, motherboard etc. Shall I install them in Ubuntu too?

I looked on the web for my Nvidia drivers and I have found a `.run` file. How could I install it on my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 366):

Occasionally, some applications and games (eg. some from the Humble Indie Bundle) have .run installers. Before installing using these, check to see if:

1. it is available from the Software Centre
2. it is available as a .deb file, which will open in the Software Center

You can install .run files from the graphical interface, but using a terminal is more likely to give you useful feedback. To install a .run file you need to:

1. make it executable.
2. execute it

This is because .run files are just executable programs that do some unknown magic to install the program. This is similar to what .exe installers do on Windows and is different to the normal methods (at best, using the Software Centre, at worst using .deb files) in which applications are installed in a standard way and can be easily removed.

**Graphical Method**

1. Right click on the file in the file manager and click 'Properties'. Click the 'Permissions' tab and tick the box that says 'Allow executing file as program'.
2. Double click the file to execute it.

If this method doesn't work, try using the terminal method.

**Terminal Method**

Assume the file is called `some-app.run` and is in the folder `/home/user/Downloads`. You will need to modify these instructions to fit your situation.

1. Open a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal).
2. enter `cd /home/user/Downloads`
3. enter `chmod +x some-app.run`
4. enter `./some-app.run`
5. **if** step 4 fails with a message including 'permission denied', try entering `sudo ./some-app.run` (you will need to enter your password for this).

## Notes

- Sometimes you will come across .bin files. These are *similar* to .run files from the user's point of view.
- The method to install .run files can be used to execute any file (as long as it has some sort of executable code in it.
- Be careful using `sudo` and only use it when absolutely required. Translated into English, it means 'Run this command but allow it to do anything it wants to my computer'. This is why you are prompted for your password.

Comment: What can i do in the last step if i have an AMD driver? You said to enter: sudo nvidia-xconfig --add-argb-glx-visuals, but that won't work for me cuz i have AMD :/

Comment: were 'chmod +x some-app.run' is used to set the file as executable

Comment: It tells me `sudo ./filename.run command not found` after I enter my sudo password

Comment: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.4-0-installer.run: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: I just want to say, this is a great answer format. Few assumptions and shortcuts taken. Thank you for spending quality time on it!

Comment: Would you mind explaining step 4? What does the ./ before the file name mean or do? Cheers

Comment: @andrew `./filename` means `filename` is a file in the CURRENT directory, execute it. This is to protect us from - imagine we are in a directory with a malicious executable called `ls`; we do a `ls` command to see what files are there, but instead call the executable. Thus the need for './'.

Comment: Excellent explanation, but how can we add an icon to our desktop? I installed a software but how can I initialize it?

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Both versions are working : graphical and terminal.

Answer (score 47):

**Installing .run files in ubuntu:**

- Open a terminal(Applications>>Accessories>>Terminal).
- Navigate to the directory of the **.run** file.
- If you have your *.run in your desktop then type the following in terminal to get into Desktop and press Enter.

  `cd ~/Desktop`
- Then type `chmod +x filename.run` and press Enter.
- Now type `./filename.run`  and press Enter, and the installer will run.

Comment: Installing drivers by .run files is **not recommended** for unexperienced users. See dv3500ea's answer.

Comment: @Takkat Ya i know that.But his question was how to install .run files that's why i answered that part alone.

Comment: perfectly o.k. :) I just felt a comment on this may save some support time ;)

Comment: It tells me `sudo ./filename.run command not found` after I enter my sudo password

Answer (score 18):

To run the file, open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/file.run
sudo /path/to/file.run
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sudo sh "path to your .run file"
```

-Worked for installing MyEclipse

Answer (score 4):

**open new terminal**

```
sudo -s -H
```

**then browse to the .run file**

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
./xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux based OS there are no .exe files, and Linux is fully permission based. Whatever you want to do, you first need to give permission.

You are asking how to install .run file?

By default, files you copy on the system don't get the executable permission because by default in Linux the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is set to 022.

To make your .run file executable or working:

```
sudo chmod +x filename.run
```

Then it will ask for the password.

- [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html) is a way to authenticate and run commands as the [superuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser).
- `chmod +x` gives executable permission to that file to all type of users.

Comment: @Dishank Often `sudo` is unnecessary for changing permissions on a .run file--sometimes these files need to be run as root, but usually they're owned by the user's non-root account (because they're usually downloaded in a web browser or with a command like `wget`, run as the non-root user).

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA "runfile" you get with the CUDA Toolkit is a [Makeself](https://makeself.io/) shell script that is a self-extracting installer. It is used by making the shell script executable with `chmod +x` and then running the script like `./cuda_xx_linux.run`. As proof, here are the first few lines of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script was generated using Makeself 2.1.4

CRCsum="1245122594"
MD5="af9acef1fff4d3c4e02942175ee1f007"
TMPROOT=${TMPDIR:=/tmp}

label="NVIDIA CUDA PACKAGE"
script="./cuda-installer"
scriptargs=""
targetdir="pkg"
filesizes="3029608617"
keep=n
```