# How To Install New Nvidia Linux Driver Supports Ubuntu 11.04 Series 270.41.06?

Tags: installation, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install .run files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18747/how-do-i-install-run-files)

My friends tell to me about New Nvidia linux driver and can supports Ubuntu 11.04, But I can't install on my Ubuntu right now because the extensions it's different (.run) not (.deb). I'm so confuse about that, would you like to answers this?
Thanks Masters!