# can't set resolution matrox video card

Tags: server, video, matrox

I built my first server and displayed `1920X1080` properly through the built in video VGA, on MOBO.  After confirming that worked I installed `Matrox M9120 PCI x16` and was lowered to `1024X768` resolution.

I downloaded the proper `.run` file and followed some instructions i found on Google to unpack the drivers and run them `./[name].run`.  Terminal showed the drivers installed.  As a long time Windows user my train of thought was the proper resolution would be enabled.  Not as such!  Any tips on what I am doing incorrectly?

Also when I installed 8GB of ram, it shows 7.9GB installed.  With 16GB it showed 15.7 installed.  I had assumed that the system allocated some RAM to video when I was using VGA.  When I turned MOBO video off in BIOS it continued to display 15.7gB free.  Is this video related or simply Linux's way of showing RAM count?

Comment: List down the steps you've done to install the driver

Comment: I used this page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18747/how-do-i-install-run-files

and used the commands (replacing with matrox file name):
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86-185.18.36-pkg1.run

sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-185.18.36-pkg1.run

However I realize I did not do:
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop

Comment: you have to do sudo service lightdm stop

Answer (score 0):

First you have to switch to non graphical tty suppose tty1 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

login with username and password

stop lightdm: `sudo stop lightdm`

Give execute permission to the .run file driver `sudo chmod +x driver.run`

Now run the script by `sudo ./driver.run`

then reboot and you should now be working on the new driver

Comment: ctrl+alt+F1 gave no prompt so I tried ctrl+alt+F2.  in tty2, i typed what you said and any version of stop lightdm gives "stop: uknown instance:"

continuing to ./driver.run gives "you must be logged in as root to run this program"

Comment: i found that sudo su, fixed the second issue.  I booted into command interface and still get the issue with stopping lightdm.  drivers show installed but I cannot change rez