# How to get a downloaded file to run / install

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded a program to the downloads folder, it is as pasted......

```
/home/rod/Downloads/eagle-lin32-7_6_0-1.run
```

The question is : How do I get it to install or run??
The program is for Linux 32 bit but I cannot find any way to get it to go.
Regards,
Rod. J.

Comment: Is your installation of Ubuntu a 32 bit? If yes: `chmod +x /home/rod/Downloads/eagle-lin32-7_6_0-1.run && ./home/rod/Downloads/eagle-lin32-7_6_0-1.run`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install .run files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18747/how-do-i-install-run-files)

Answer (score 0):

This one line command should do the trick

```
chmod +x /home/rod/Downloads/eagle-lin32-7_6_0-1.run && ./home/rod/Downloads/eagle-lin32-7_6_0-1.run
```

Since run is an executable you have to use the terminal to run

```
./(executable-file-with-extension)
```