# How to install GPU drivers in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers

I'm using **AMD Radeon x1600/1650 Series** GPU in my system, i installed Ubuntu today because i was too bored from Windows. My question is, i downlaoded .run file from the official AMD driver website but i don't know how to install it. Also is there any similar thing to Windows Device Management in ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install .run files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18747/how-do-i-install-run-files) and [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/q/815591/)

Comment: Seems like but how can i be sure that i installed the driver?

Comment: To check if an AMD driver is installed run `inxi -Gx`

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/q38ggo any help ? (click the link to see the picture)

Comment: [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1109982/)