# Unable to install PIA

Tags: vpn

I have downloaded PIA for Ubuntu from the official PIA site.
When it downloads it is in a .run file
There are no instructions on how to install PIA on my 21.04 system.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install .run files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18747/how-do-i-install-run-files)

Answer (score 4):

PIA does a pretty good job of hiding the install instructions, they can be found here:
https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/guides/linux/linux-installing-the-pia-app#linux-installing-the-pia-app_step-1-download

It's actually pretty simple:

Open a terminal

Move to the directory containing the .run file:

```
$ cd Downloads
```

Run the file using sh (do not use sudo) and enter your password when prompted:

```
$ sh pia-linux-3.1-06756.run
```

The app should automatically open when the script finishes. Log in with your PIA credentials and you'll be good to go.

You may have to make the file executable, in which case run this command before running the .run file:

```
$ sudo chmod u+x /path/to/pia-linux-3.1-06756.run
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I do agree that they do a good job at trying to hide their installer.

I have just discovered an easier way to install it.

Open a terminal

Drag and drop the .run file its download location into the terminal

Press return.

Worked for me :-)

Comment: Thanks for the -1 but if it worked for me, then I do not see why it should be marked down